# Type cast error when I cast webdriver javascriptExecutor to Dictionary

Tags: webdriver, navigation-timing-api

All,

I am trying to use Navigation Timing API in my webdriver project. This is what I tried but it throws error

```js
public static Dictionary<String, Object> getTimingAPI(){
  try{
   Dictionary<String, Object> dict = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
   dict =   (Dictionary<String ,Object>) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)executeScript("var performance = window.performance || window.webkitPerformance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || {}; var timings = performance.timing || {};return timings;");
   return dict;
  }catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Find browser timing : " + e);
      }
  return null;
 }
```

Error:
:

```js
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to java.util.Dictionary
```

.

I tried to cast to String , Object etc. but always it throws error. I am wondering what will be the return Object of this java script.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have resolved this by changing JS to return individual timings and assigned to object, rather returning all timings.

Answer (score 1):

This way it works.

Map(String, Object) map = new HashMap(String, Object)();

map =  (Map(String, Object)) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
          .executeScript(JS_SCRIPT);

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by changing JS to return individual timings and assigned to object, rather returning all timings.

```js
Object start =    (Object) ((JavascriptExecutor) NavigationHelper.getWebDriver()).executeScript("var performance = window.performance || window.webkitPerformance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || {}; var timings = performance.timing.navigationStart || {};return timings;");
```